# why EventEmitter doesn't return first value?

Tags: angular

I have a problem with eventemitter , that is when i add data in child class and passes the data into parent by EventEmitter , i am  facing a problem that parent is not able to get first data when child add, the first data was child added only getting to parent  when second data added in child

**Child Components**

```
    saveData()
        {
         this.dialog.closeAll();
          this.getData();
           const body={
                name:this.model.name,
               age:this.model.age
                 }
          // this.arrayCalendar.push(body);
         this.calendarService.previewdata.emit(body)
               }
```

**parent component**

```
      handleDateClick(arg) {

const data={};
this.dialog.open(AddPatientComponent,{
  data:{data},
  width:"200px",
  height:"300px"

})
 this.calendarService.previewdata.subscribe(message => this.result = message);
console.log("DATA FROM PARENT"+JSON.stringify(this.result))
if(this.result)
{
    this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.concat({ 

    title: this.result.name,
    start: arg.date,
    allDay: arg.allDay
  })
}
```

}

**service**

```
      constructor() { }
      public previewdata = new EventEmitter();
```

Anyone Know the reason behind that?

Comment: Generally, event emitter is used in a different way. Anyway, you should log the result inside the subscription not outside it.

Comment: Why are you using an event emitter in a service? EventEmitters are used for binding to events in the HTML. You can just use a `Subject` of some kind if you're subscribing to it in code

Answer (score 1):

You should move the code that depends on the EventEmitter's value inside the subscribe block.

```
this.calendarService.previewdata.subscribe(message => this.result = message);
console.log("DATA FROM PARENT"+JSON.stringify(this.result))
if(this.result)
{
    this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.concat({ 
    title: this.result.name,
    start: arg.date,
    allDay: arg.allDay
  })
}
```

should be

```
this.calendarService.previewdata.subscribe(message => {
 this.result = message;
 console.log("DATA FROM PARENT"+JSON.stringify(this.result))
    if(this.result)
    {
        this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.concat({ 
        title: this.result.name,
        start: arg.date,
        allDay: arg.allDay
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: But i am facing a problem . that is when i add child, am getting the name mutliple times Eg: first click,name will be one time, second time add a event, get name of event twice like that

Comment: @CodeIgniter where are you using this block of code? It should be generally inside ngOnInit. If you're subscribing inside a class function make sure that you're calling that properly.

Comment: the result form the service  getting in to handleDateClick(arg)

Comment: from here i take the name into front end , but no of time when child add the data , the same count of data is retrieve from service or say same no:of times it calls service

Comment: @CodeIgniter I'm not entirely sure about what you're trying to do but if you are subscribing inside a function make sure that the function gets executed before emitting an event. If the part inside subscribe is getting called multiple times then you might be emitting the event more times than what you need.

Comment: I am not calling service multiple times , I am working on  a full calendar , so based on the value getting from eventemitter ,i need to set that value as event name

Comment: in first case , that is when i add data first time ,it works perfectly . then when i add again the data of current are added two times and so on

Comment: You're not calling service multiple times but you are subscribing multiple times, that's what cause your issue

Comment: How i am subscribing?, if im , how can i avoid

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would suggest some serious refactoring. If you want to use `emitter` use it without the service, that's some weird design.

Second, don't subscribe in the function which handles click. This might lead to weird behavior, like what you experiencing now, if you don't unsubscribe properly.

If you want to use service, remove the `emitter` and replace it with some subject and observable.

**Service:**

```
private _previewData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); //use proper type instead of any
previewData$: Observable<any> = this._previewData.asObservable(); //same here

constructor() {}

// and correct type here instead of any
pushUpdate(dialogData: any): void {
  this._previewData.next(dialogData);
}
```

**Child:**

```
saveData(): void {
  // I'm not sure what dialog you use but I have a feeling that the code below
  // should be moved to subscribe or then
  this.dialog.closeAll();
  this.getData();

  const body = {
    name:this.model.name,
    age:this.model.age
  }

  this.calendarService.pushUpdate(body);
}
```

**Parent:**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.calendarService.previewData$
    .pipe(
      // Add console log to see what data are pushed
      tap(data => console.log('previewData:', data)),
      // Remove if it fails for no obvious reason and do the check in subscribe
      filter(data => !!data)
    )
    .subscribe(message => {
      // Do whatever you want to do with your data here
      this.result = message

      if (this.result) {
        this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.concat({ 
          title: this.result.name,
          start: arg.date,
          allDay: arg.allDay
       });
    });
}

handleDateClick(arg) {
  const data={};
  this.dialog.open(AddPatientComponent, {
    data:{data},
    width:"200px",
    height:"300px"
  });
  // It looks like you are using Angular Material, have you tried 
  // handling data returned from dialog in aferClosed() observable?
  // dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {...});
}
```

Comment: He can also directly subscribe to the subject(_previewData) instead of taking a new property that does `.asObservable()`? Actually I'm seeing this pattern a lot..what's the reason?

Comment: Sure you can but it's not the best way. This is a good article about that: https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

Comment: are you sure that to use filter inside the pipe?

Comment: Try it without it, it was supposed to replace `if(this.result)`. I'll update my answer, check for alternative

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz? It's difficult to say without it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209362/discussion-between-codeigniter-and-dallows).